# Does my "question" fit in Programmers Q/A

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have seen questions in Programmers asking for advice on "resume".

I followed most of the stuff and wrote my resume (PHP). I want to seek advice to find the possible negatives in my resume and also if any, I am keen on taking advice to become a better programmer.

Can I ask this kind of question in Programmers?

Comment: thanks for asking. As far as I can tell, resume help and career advice are off-topic per **[faq](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq)**

Comment: @gnat The stackexchange is a great community. Is there any site under stackexchange where it is suitable.

Comment: "seek advice" kind question might be too open ended for any SE site I'm afraid. If you've got specific (answerable constructively) problem to solve, take a look at Workplace; they've got pretty active tags "resume" and "career-development". Prior to posting your question, take an effort to check their **[about page](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/about)**: "It's not a discussion forum... etc"

Comment: It should be noted that the Workplace explicitly says they do not review Resumes in their FAQ. You can ask a specific question about your resume, but if you post your resume and ask for a review of it then they will probably close your question pretty fast. You might find someone willing to review your Resume in [their chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) though. Can't hurt to ask at least. :)